# Conflict between mouseup and mousedown events?

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-events

I made a table with different cells (`input` elements) in it:

```
<?php 
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input name="test00" value="0"></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="test01" value="1"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input name="test10" value="2"></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="test11" value="3"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
?>
```

And have the following jQuery code:

```
$('input[name^="test"]').mousedown(function(event) 
{
    //event.preventDefault();
    var field=$(this);        
    field.css({background : "#BFE7F5"});       
});

$('input[name^="test"]').on( "mouseup", function() 
{
    //var id-cellule;
    //var id-colonne;
    var field=$(this);

    field.css({background : "#AAAAAA"});
});
```

#### The problem:

When I release the mouse (`mouseup` event) outside of the cell, this function still is executed on the cell where the `mousedown` event occurred.

I want to allow the user to select several cells, so when `mousedown` occurs on a cell, this will be the first selected cell. Then on `mouseup`, the cell indicated by the mouse should be the last selected one.

I made the above example with a sample table to make it easier to understand.

I tried using `preventDefault()`, but then none of the inputs are editable any more.

```js
$('input[name^="test"]').mousedown(function(event) // Pour tous les input qui changeront
                                   {
  //event.preventDefault();
  var field=$(this);        
  field.css({background : "#BFE7F5"});       
});
$('input[name^="test"]').on( "mouseup", function() // Pour tous les input qui changeront
                            {
  //var id-cellule;
  //var id-colonne;
  var field=$(this);
  field.css({background : "#AAAAAA"});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test00" value="0"></td>
    <td><input name="test01" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test10" value="2"></td>
    <td><input name="test11" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of the `mouseup` event is the `input` element that has the focus, even if your mouse position is on another element. Even with event delegation, or by requesting `$(':hover')`, you will still get that `input` element that has the focus.

Instead, calculate from the mouse position which is the element you are hovering over, and if it is an `input` element, perform the CSS modification:

```js
$('input[name^="test"]').mousedown(function(event) {
    $(this).css({background : "#BFE7F5"});       
});
$('input[name^="test"]').on( "mouseup", function(e) {
    $hoverElem = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY))
        .filter('input[name^="test"]');
    $hoverElem.css({background : "#AAAAAA"})
              .focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test00" value="0"></td>
    <td><input name="test01" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test10" value="2"></td>
    <td><input name="test11" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, this seems to solve the problem, it works on that sample.

Comment: Excuse me, in fact, for a simple css modify it works, but in my programm case, I need to execute a big ammount of code, not just a css line. will it be working using that tip? and if yes, could you please tell me how to implement it?

Comment: If you need to do more than just css, then assign the element to a variable (I updated my answer to show this). Try it. If you still have a problem, ask a new question with the specific problem you encounter.

Comment: ok thanks, I will test it, and reply a bit later regarding the results I got

Comment: ok, so I confirm your solution is the one that solved my problem.

Comment: great thanks, you made my day(sorry for additional comment, but cannot edit the previous one...)

Comment: NB: you can always delete comments of your own (there is a little cross at the end when you hover your mouse over your comments). And if you are fast, you can even edit them (within 5 minutes after posting).

Comment: thanks, good to know for delete(and for editing I confirm it is not possible, only delete, maybe cause I have new account?)

Comment: I'm not sure when that becomes available. Maybe when you have 50 reputation points. It appears as an "edit" link at the right of your comment that is less than 5 minutes old.

Answer (score 1):

try mouseout event of jquery.
just replace mouseup to mouseout.

[code][EDITED}

```
$('input').mousedownr(function(event) // Pour tous les input qui changeront
{
    var field_nm=$(this).attr("name");
    //event.preventDefault();
    var field=$(this);        
    field.css({background : "#BFE7F5"});       
});
$('input').on( "mouseup", function() // Pour tous les input qui changeront
{
    var field_nm=$(this).attr("name");
    //var id-cellule;
    //var id-colonne;
    var field=$(this);
    field.css({background : "#AAAAAA"
});
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully... the `mouseup` already works fine.

Comment: then try  mouseout instead mouseup

Comment: I just tried it, but it is not the expected I want, maybe I didn't explain well :

Comment: I just tried it, but it is not the expected I want, maybe I didn't explain well :
I want to execute "mousedown" on a cell, then "mouseup" on a different cell.

Comment: try this... just change like this : $('input').mouseup(function(){ var name= $(this).attr("name"); });

Comment: if I press the mouse button on the cell "test00", then I unpress button on "test01", the result may be :
test00 color=#BFE7F5, and test01 color=#AAAAAA
If I use "mouseout", test00 color=#AAAAAA as soon as I go out of the cell

Comment: @GhanshyamAshra update your answer instead of puting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `mouseup` listner to the `document` so you can detect the out of input `mouseup` then init the `start_input` to the white color :

```js
var start_input;

$('input[name^="test"]').mousedown(function(event){
  var field=$(this);

  field.css({background : "#BFE7F5"});       
  start_input=field;
});

$(document).on( "mouseup", function(e){
  var field=$(e.target);

  if( e.target.tagName=="INPUT" ){
    field.css({background : "#AAAAAA"});
  }else{
    start_input.css({background : "#FFFFFF"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test00" value="0"></td>
    <td><input name="test01" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test10" value="2"></td>
    <td><input name="test11" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

So for mouseout it is not the good one.
for second proposition,
I added the following :

var name= $(this).attr("name");
console.log(name);

But the name is the name of the cell where I pressed the mouse button(where I launched mousedown).

Comment: Please don't post this as an answer. If you need to provide extra information, edit your question, and add a paragraph in it.